# Laptop shutting down instead of sleeping on battery power

Tags: battery, sleep, shutdown

I have set my laptop to sleep after 5 minutes of inactivity.

But, suddenly one day, it started shutting down instead of sleeping when on battery power.

When plugged in, it sleeps after 5 minutes of inactivity, but only when on battery power, it shuts down.

I have also updated the driver to the Intel(R) Management Engine Interface, I have disabled and enabled it after that, yet no change. I read that we need to uncheck the Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power, but there is no Power Management tab on the Intel(R) Management Engine Interface on my laptop.

I have checked my settings and they are set to sleep on both battery power and when plugged in.

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long does this laptop work on battery power when you're using it actively?

Comment: What @gronostaj wishes to check is if your battery at end of life.

Comment: If its 100% charged, it works for about 45 mins  - 1 hour till I need to charge it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can open device manager, locate the device Intel(R) Management Engine Interface and right click it > Device properties and then uncheck Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power. This worked for me earlier.

Comment: Please see the newly edited question.